# JavaScript - Get the difference from the 2nd array

Tags: javascript

I have this 2 array:

```
let field1 = [ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four' ];
let field2 = [ 'one', 'three', 'six' ];
```

Now I want the output should be `six`

I am trying :

```
console.log( field1.filter(x => !field2.includes(x)) );
```

but maybe something is wrong here.

Comment: You flipped `field1` and `field2`. Look into [How to get the difference between two arrays in JavaScript?](/q/1187518/4642212).

Comment: Oh, Yes, you right :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want:

```js
let field1 = [ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four' ];
let field2 = [ 'one', 'three', 'six' ];
const answer = field2.filter(it => !field1.includes(it));
console.log(answer); // ['six']
```

Or you can use indexOf to check if any item of the second array is not present in the first array like this:

```js
let field1 = [ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four' ];
let field2 = [ 'one', 'three', 'six' ];
function diff(arr1, arr2) {
    const arr3 = [];
    for (const x of arr2) {
        if (arr1.indexOf(x) < 0) {
            arr3.push(x);
        }
    }
    return arr3;
}
const answer = diff(field1, field2);
console.log(answer);
```

Answer (score 1):

just swap 2 variables field1, field2

how about this?

```
 field2.filter(ele => !field1.includes(ele))[0]
```